# How do I check the DPI (dots per inch) of an image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to find out the DPI of the image that the user has selected using ImagePicker. I have used the `image` and `exif` package to find out it's XResolution but the exif data of the image is empty in both cases.

```
Future<bool> isImageDPIValid(Uint8List imageData) async {
    final image = img.decodeImage(imageData);
    final data = await readExifFromBytes(imageData);

    print('IMAGE EXIF DATA :  $data');
    if (image != null) {
      final dpi = image.exif.imageIfd.XResolution?.toDouble() ?? 0;
      final dpi2 = image.exif.interopIfd.XResolution?.toDouble() ?? 0;
      final exif = image.exif;
      print('EFIX : ${exif.imageIfd.data}');
      print('DPI OF IMAGE :  $dpi $dpi2');
      return dpi >= 300.0;
    }
    return false;
  }
```